# Using Go To X,Y dialog box with UTM coordinates in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, utm

Someone gave me x,y coordinate numbers in Meters, and I put them in the Go To X,Y tool of ArcMap, but ArcMap displayed them in the wrong place.

I checked the bottom on the right corner and that says they are in meters.

Is it possible that ArcMap 9.3.1 gave the wrong location when I entered the UTM 13 NAD 1983 numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entering UTM coordinates on this dialog is a little tricky:

From the help on [Using the Go to X, Y dialog box](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00660000043r000000.htm):

> Click the **Units** button [image: Units] to choose the units in which to enter coordinates.
>
> - When using MGRS, USNG, or UTM locations, make sure there are no spaces in the coordinate string.
>
> **Valid UTM coordinate notation input:** 17N6734294749123 (1-meter square, 13-digit coordinate)

**So the zone 13N would go first, followed by the first 6 digits of the easting (X-coordinate) followed by the first 7 digits of the northing (Y-coordinate), with no spaces in between.**

I will say the help is woefully inadequate regarding how the easting/northing must be entered.

Comment: An addition to your answer: When adding UTM coordinates to the Go to X, Y dialog box, the correct zone can be found using a grid like this one: http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm

I find this especially confusing since UTM zones are often broken up only into N (north) and S (south), but the system ESRI uses for this tool breaks them into 20. Adding to this confusion, I work primarily in latitudinal zone S, which is north of the equator....

When I first saw 17R in the help topic you linked to above, it was a real head-scratcher! But when I realized they were using this grid, it became clear.

Comment: 17N6734294749123 is the most ESRI thing ever...