# Correct format for Easting/Northing in Go To XY tool in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, coordinates, xy

I am trying to create a point in ArcGIS Pro based on Easting and Northing coordinates that I obtain from an online map viewer. The online map viewer only has the Easting and Northing and does not have any other information about the online map.

When I put the Easting and Northing coordinates into the Go To XY tool together with my UTM zone at the start, it sends me into the ocean on the equator instead of the correct location.

I am wondering if there is something wrong I am getting about entering the data into the Go To XY box?

What I've tried:

1. Putting my UTM zone plus the Easting and Northing into one string, as described here: [Using Go To X,Y dialog box with UTM coordinates in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20031/using-go-to-x-y-dialog-box-with-utm-coordinates-in-arcmap)

This puts me on the equator, in the ocean somewhere west of South America.

2. Changing the UTM zone code as per this map: [www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm)

This also puts me on the equator and in the ocean, but a bit east of the last point.

Thoroughly stumped as to what to try next.

The ArcGIS Pro ESRI help section on the Go To XY tool did not have any details on this, unfortunately.

The coordinates I tried:

Easting = 312,940
Northing = 1,104,179

What I typed in the Go To box:

18N3129401104179 and 18T3129401104179.

Both versions brought me to the same spot in the ocean (screenshots attached).

The map in ArcGIS I am trying it with is the default web projection, which is what I was told the source map is, whose attribute table provided the Easting and Northing.

[image: Screenshot of pin location - #1]
[image: Screenshot of pin location - #2]

Comment: My map in ArcGIS Pro is NAD 1983 UTM Zone 18N. I typed in "18N" + Easting (6 digits) + Northing (7 digits) all as one string in the dialog box. I am not sure about the coordinate system/projection of the online map that I got the Easting and Northing from.

Comment: I also tried "18T" with the rest of the string the same, as that was the letter for my region in the map in link 2.

Comment: Your comment says your map is in "NAD 1983 UTM Zone 18N" but in the question body you seem to be saying that it's in Web Mercator.  Which is it?

Comment: The maps I work with usually on the work/home computer are NAD 1983 UTM Zone 18N. The map that I am pulling the data from (Easting/Northing) is a web map that is in Web Mercator. The web map has the Easting/Northing as attributes when you point at the tax parcels, or you can also download the data as csv. But when I try the coordinates I get from the web map, it does not match the tax parcels in my own map, even if I make my own map in Web Mercator (I tried starting a new map in Pro in Web Mercator and used the coordinates, and it still put me in the ocean).